# Эпоха внутри эпохи

Tags: выбор-слов, семантика, синонимы, история, даты

Можно ли говорить об "эпохе" в связи с правлением того или иного царя (императора), например *эпоха Петра I?* Можно ли на самых различных основаниях объединять понятием "эпоха" периоды истории, большие или меньшие (например, эпоха реализма в литературе охватывает эпохи многих правителей России)? Корретно ли выражение "эпоха правления Петра" или лучше просто "эпоха Петра"?

Answer (score 2):

Начнем со словаря:
[эпоха](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%8D%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B0), -и; ***ж.*** [от греч. *epochē* — остановка]
**1.** Продолжительный период времени, имеющий какие-либо характерные особенности. *Эпоха Возрождения. **Эпоха Петра I.** Советская эпоха. Современная эпоха. Новая эпоха в мировой истории. Эпоха в чьей-либо жизни* (важный, значительный период жизни). // О периоде времени, когда какое-либо явление получает широкое распространение. *Эпоха немого кино. Эпоха мини-моды.*

Думаю, что можно говорить и *эпоха правления Петра* (1689—1725), и *эпоха Петра*, подразумевая, конечно же, бо́льший период времени: годы жизни императора (1672—1725).

Из [справочника по истории](https://books.google.ee/books?id=DFMUEAAAQBAJ&pg=PA116&lpg=PA116&dq=%22%D1%8D%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%22&source=bl&ots=7-TGzejKsa&sig=ACfU3U2uvtpvmVkiNPXnrPXlRpd-vqPGpw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi7tcDVuNL4AhUW6CoKHfFDDpU4ChDoAXoECBIQAw#v=onepage&q=%22%D1%8D%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%22&f=false) (Сергей Кужель):

> ```
>                         Эпоха правления Петра I  
>     (годы жизни: 1672—1725, годы действительного правления: 1689—1725)
> ```
>
> В 1689 г. в Москве произошла попытка стрелецкого бунта, Софья была отстранена от власти и выслана в монастырь. Началась эпоха правления Петра I.